# Working with IIFE file that used to be an ES6 class-based file

Tags: javascript, iife

I was working with an ES6 class-based file I developed but because of compatibility issues with IE11, I had to use RollupJS to transpile the class-based file to an Immediately Invoked Function Expression, the problem with that is that in the root `index.js` file, the class-based file was instantiated like so:

```
import { XCode } from './Library/Transform/xcode-es6.js';
import * as uIHandler from './Library/Transform/UIHandler.js'

try {
  const handler = new uIHandler();
  const sdk = XCode();
  sdk.setHandler(handler);
}
```

We are getting an error where it cannot find the `uIHandler`, I believe the problem is not with the import statement up top, but that we can no longer instantiate an IIFE type file. If I am correct, what would the solution be here? I have very limited experience with IIFE.

Comment: The problem definitely is with the import statement, as `import * as uIHandler from …` is a namespace import and `uiHandler` will definitely not be a constructor function that you can call with `new`. Please show us the ES6 source of that module.

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply RollupJS to the entire program, and not just pieces of it.

It has converted `UIHandler.js` so it is no longer an ES6 module, so you can't treat it as one any more.

Comment: right, if I understand you correctly then that means we cannot instantiate an IIFE.

Comment: @Daniel An IIFE is not a function, it's an expression that calls the function and returns its return value. The function is nested inside as a temporary value, there's no way to instantiate it.

Comment: @Barmar, that's what I thought, but I am not sure what the alternative approach then is